# use tabs inside Excel 2010 cells

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm struggling with this issue for quite some time now and can't find the solution I want to. I'm looking for a solution to tab between two or three words/values inside a single Excel 2010 cell. I'm organising multiple types of cameras with different aspects as listed below:

- 800x600 pixels, fixed iris, etc, etc.
- 1280x720 pixels, DC-iris, etc, etc.
- 1920x1080 pixels, P-iris, etc, etc.

One solution is to use the Courier font and just use spaces to get all the data properly aligned because all letters have the same X ratio with this font. However this font is not part of our company policy and I don't like the font either so it's not the thing I'm looking for.

Another solution is to create multiple smaller columns ofcourse and put every type of data in a single column. Unfortunatly this is getting quite messy as well because eventually 99% of all the cameras are filtered out and only 1% is shown (it's some sort of standard calculation sheet). It can occur that this 1% misses some aspects and the huge blank lines appear.

I hope I explained my problem properly. Does anyone have a solution for this or isn't it possible at all?

Comment: you're dealing with data that's multi-dimensional in nature, and excel is inherently 2D-only. there's some hackish workarounds using validation and vlookup(), but they're ugly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. However I only wish to tab or space the words after every comma so they start at the same point under each other. The entire Excel sheet is filled with cross references and stuff but my problem is just a simple alignment issue in a single cell.

Comment: Excel isn't a good word processor. Can you use headers (Pixels, Iris, Etc., Etc.) and enter the data in the column below the header? With the data the way you have described it removes the ability to sort or filter because all the data is in one cell.

Answer (score 1):

Put the data in cells/columns. That's what Excel is designed to handle. You can merge, align shrink and grow the columns to get the alignment you want.

Don't try and force a round peg through a square cell.